# Wi-Fi cannot turn on! Accidentally deleted /etc/wifi folder

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, rom-flashing, custom-roms, recovery-mode

i was trying to enable ad hoc network connection on android and overwriting below folders

/etc/wifi

/etc/dhcpcd

and now my wifi could not turn on. The phone is ADINNO R8, a custom build phone.I could not find its ROM on the internet and most of software does not recognize it.

it runs on 4.2.1 Jelly bean.

tried:

- USB internet

USB internet to upgrade firmware within OS(seems to use wifi driver as well which are corrupted, so there is no internet connection)

- 3rd party fixer

download WiFi fixer and not working

- other version/wifi folders

downloaded some WiFi folders people upload on the internet and none of them are working.(maybe because this is a rare custom phone)

- Recovery

tried recovery and wipe all data in setting, still no luck, wifi folder still corrupted.

i could think of three methods, both failed.

1. reflash its OS.(failed as could not find its ROM)
2. upgrade its OS.(failed as no internet access, WiFi not working)
3. Replace /etc/wifi found on internet (failed as no compatible version)

is there anyway i could fix it?

Comment: Is there an upgrade waiting to be installed even?

Answer (score 1):

Try harder to find firmware images for your phone. A factory reset might not work, as it only wipes data and cache partition. The etc folder is in /system/etc, /etc usually just is a link to /system/etc. Therefore you would need an image of the system partiton.
Well, if you can't find such firmware, it might not be a device thats common used, and therefore - if you are lucky - there was not a lot of money around for software adaptations from the manufacturor. Try to get firmware for similar devices, watch out for the same android version, and second on similar hardware / components. Download these images, unpack them and try to find the needed files.
Maybe you can just grab another device, from a friend or so, and look for the files. You might also consider having a look on aosp and taking the files from there. Watch out for the correct android version.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. However, as Armando Gonzalez said, there is really not much information for the mentioned phone model...and it consist of 7 hardware button and 3 touch screen buttons. It's really hard really hard to find similar firmware as well... I will keep trying though.

Comment: As harder it is to find it, as closer it might be to the official aosp, Android OpenSource Project. The source can also easily be searched on androidxref.com. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to do a Factory Reset through Settings. I deleted a system file once and it ended up fixing it although my new experience with Android says it might not work. I couldn't find anything online relating to your phone besides reviews, tests, and things along those lines. You are sort of in a pickle here. I'll try to search more for ya.

Comment: Thanks for the searching... tried factory reset through setting. only deleted my user data...Wifi still not fix.

Comment: @BuWenliang  same here ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Is there an upgrade waiting to be installed even?

I have 2 ideas:

A: Use bluetooth tethering to your phone to get network access

B: You could install some basic commandline tools (eg. ssh server / socat / brctl / etc) from http://dan.drown.org/android/ and try to get a working connection via Android-Debug-Bridge's integrated portforwarding feature (maybe setting a proxy to this port works)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried using inserting a SIM card. There is no update available.

Answer (score 0):

Contact someone from the review of this phone and ask him if he can do a **/system/etc**  backup and upload it to the internet.Than just restore it.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to [post comments](//android.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't have that many reputation, cause i just registered so it would be helpful if someone helps me get it not down voting cause I can't  comment.

Comment: Please understand you cannot or are not supposed  to subvert the rules. The reputation needed to comment is only 50+ which can be gained by posting one or two high-quality answers (+10 for upvote, +15  if accepted), or post good quality questions (+5 on each). I've told you on your other posts, so as one other user, to not to post answers in such way. I hope would understand, and I'm looking forward for some good answers from you. See you soon! :)